# How come my python batch file closes once its done?

Tags: python, batch-file, cmd

Im trying to prevent the cmd to close when script is done and print out the message and wait for the users input and THEN close but it just closes as soon as its done.. what am I doing wrong?

```
except tweepy.TweepError as e:
    print(e.reason)
    sleep(10)
    continue
except StopIteration:
    break
    print('Automation Done! ' + number + ' times! Press Any Key To Continue...')
    input()
```

Comment: remove the `break` statement?

Comment: I did, it didnt change it unfortunatly

Comment: Use `raw_input()` instead, or else you will likely get `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing`. Also, saying "Press Any Key To Continue" is wrong - only the return/enter key will actually continue. But of course, if it's not printing, then clearly the `StopIteration` exception is never getting generated - you should look into why that's happening. And, once it does print, you'll want to make sure to cast the number as a string, since otherwise you will see `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects`

Comment: Well then `StopIteration` is never raised apparently. What does the outer code look like? Also you probably want to use `str(number)` if number is a numerical value.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a batch file, (with a .bat and not a .py) you can use

```
pause
```

or

```
pause >nul
```

EDIT:

```
pause
```

This will prompt the user for input, upon pressing any key, it will proceed.

```
pause >nul
```

This will not prompt the user for input, however, it will still behave the same as the regular pause

Answer (score 0):

If you use `os.system("pause")`, the application send to operational sistem to pause the execution. This code can solve your problem:

```
import os

    # Code...

except tweepy.TweepError as e:
    print(e.reason)
    sleep(10)
    continue
except StopIteration:
    print('Automation Done! ' + number + ' times!')
    os.system("pause")
```